# python multiprocessing on eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, synchronization, pydev, multiprocess

I write python code on eclipse using pydev.
The code is following :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
g_workercount = 1

def calc_step():
    print('calc_step started')
    q = Queue()
    p_worker = []

    for i in range(0, g_workercount):
        ww = Process(target=worker_calc_step, args=(q,i,))
        ww.start()
        p_worker.append(ww)        

    for ww in p_worker:
        ww.join()

    print('calc_step ended')



def worker_calc_step(q, n):
    print('worker_calc_step started')    

    print('worker_calc_step ended')



if __name__ == '__main__':        
    calc_step()

    print('finished')
```

It is a very simple code, and I expected the ouput would be :

```
calc_step started
worker_calc_step started
worker_calc_step ended
calc_step ended
finished
```

It is ok executing on console, 
but running on eclipse is not ok like :

```
calc_step started
calc_step ended
finished
```

I guess before starting worker process, the main process would finished.
So I added sleep code in the main process function, but it is also same in eclipse.

Do you have any idea about it?
It is a little difficult making a multiproccess code in python and eclipse for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what may be wrong there... I've tried it here inside and outside Eclipse/PyDev in Python 2 and 3 and got the same results (where I got the expected output).

Some questions to help diagnose the issue:

- Which OS are you using?
- What's the Python version?
- Have you tried running it under the debugger to see where it might fail?
- Have you tried printing to a file instead of stdout? (maybe it's starting the process but it's not properly printing to stdout?)

Comment: Thx, I use windows 10, python 3.6.3. And there were no fail message doing that, but sometimes it work as expected when debugging and I haven't tried to print out to a file. I will try it. Thanks.